# All the pleasures of life vs all pleasures of life

Tags: articles, exam-questions

This is an error spotting question asked in my exam :

> She is wealthy (a) / and can afford (b) / all the pleasures of life (c) / No error (d)

Is the **the** before pleasures correct here ? I don't think we need *the* here and removing it will make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Both are understandable.  But as you are referring to particular or specific pleasures i.e.only the pleasures related to life, it's more appropriate to use the definite article "the" in the phrase:

The pleasures of life.